# Phone does not want to take photo from Android browser

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

I have the strangest thing happening with my web application today. When I want to take a picture from my Android browser or Chrome, it throws away the whole page with this error:

> Unable to complete previous operation due to low memory

I use:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" name="file" id="file" />
```

And then I take the picture, tap "save" and then everything is gone. My phone has enough memory to save the picture and everything, but still the error is displayed.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852411/cross-device-photo-capture-for-upload may be relevant. It appears Android 3.0 and greater are supported. What version of Android are you running?...

Comment: I am using Android 4.1.2 but the strange thing is it worked about 2 days ago. And I have made no alterations to the file

Comment: When I try to upload a picture from the camera from Chrome, I receive the error: unable to complete previous operation due to low memory but I have over 3.6GB Internal space free and 1.2GB on external memory

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25528558/unable-to-complete-previous-operation-due-to-low-memory-android-browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25528558/unable-to-complete-previous-operation-due-to-low-memory-android-browsers) same issue and same phone HAHAHA tested on my wife's Sony Z1 android and works fine

Comment: I have seen that other users have been able to upload files by using Firefox. Can anyone confirm that using Firefox allows the upload to take place without the error?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok I managed to solve my own issue. I always received the following message:

> unable to complete previous operation due to low memory

On my android device I activated developer options (by tapping the build version 3-5 time I think). And then in Developers Options I ticked "Do not keep activities". Now that was my problem. If I really think about it, it makes sense. When I open my camera from my browser to take a picture, it basically leaves the page (which is stupid from the developers because I did not close the browser) and that made the problem.

So by remove the tick from "Do not keep activities" I solved the problem. Hope this can help someone in the future.

Comment: This is not the general solution ("Do not keep activities" already unchecked, and problem still present). PS: I didn't downvote